# Eat double space

Tags: spacing, macros

How can I get a command to eat an unnecessary space, consider the below:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\mycommand}[1]{#1}
\begin{document}

    %Creates single spaces
    Discussed \mycommand{before} in section 1

    %Creaetes a double space
    Discussed \mycommand{} in section 3

\end{document}
```

I have a more complicated command elsewhere, sometimes the result is 'empty' in which case a double space is created (which I don't want), the above is in effect what is happening.

I need some logic that detects if the argument is empty, and if so, eats one of the spaces.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In this minimal example, just declare

```
\newcommand{\mycommand}[1]{#1\unskip}
```

[image]

Comment: That is what I wanted. Cheers.

Comment: @ADP beware the start of a paragraph,  you might want `\leavevmode#1\unskip`

Comment: Pretty obvious, but: if you were doing more complicated stuff within the command, you should put `\unskip` at the end of everthing.  As a silly example: `\newcommand{\mycommand}[1]{\textbf{#1}\unskip}`.  I had a less trivial example that I thought printed `#1` but `...#1\unskip...` is not the answer in general!

Answer (score 2):

I think this should do the trick:

```
\newcommand{\mycommand}[1]{%
\if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax%
\ignorespaces%
\else%
#1%
\fi}
```