# Remove spaces from around a "dummy" macro

Tags: macros

In the following MWE (it's minimal, so not the original problem). As you can check there is one space on both sides of `\mycommand`. While I'm making the macro "dummy" for a specific use: can I remove one of the spaces if there would be two left?

```
\documentclass{article}

\DeclareRobustCommand\mycommand[1]{%
   \textbf{#1}%
}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\nobf[1]{%
    {\def\mycommand##1{}#1}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\def\abc{X \mycommand{Y} Z \mycommand{!}}

\abc

\nobf{\abc}

X Z

\abc

\end{document}
```

There is a doubled space between the first `X` `Z` pair:

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate(s): [Eating space before a command](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/135984/5764); [Eat double space](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/120486/5764)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason for the spaces stem from your spurious ones in your macro definition: A line break *without* `%` acts like a space. For more on this discussion, see [What is the use of percent signs (`%`) at the end of lines?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7453/5764).

A far shorter definition of `\nobf` would be

```
\newcommand\nobf[1]{{\renewcommand{\mycommand}[1]{\leavevmode\unskip\ignorespaces}#1}}
```

Note that there's no line break, so the macro doesn't introduce any spurious spaces in the output. Also, redefining `\mycommand` is done inside a group, so there's no need to save and restore the macro. The redefinition removes any skip before it (via `\unskip`) as well as ignoring any following (via `\ignorespaces`).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\DeclareRobustCommand\mycommand[1]{\textbf{#1}}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\nobf[1]{{\renewcommand{\mycommand}[1]{\leavevmode\unskip\ignorespaces}#1}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\def\abc{X \mycommand{Y} Z \mycommand{!}}

\abc

\nobf{\abc}

X Z

\abc

\end{document}
```

Comment: The output is absolutely not the same... I don't want `Y`-s an `!`-s in my output when I use `\nobf`. Sorry if the function name was misleading (they were unfortunate random characters I typed).

Comment: And even if I have a ton of `%`-s there are still two spaces between `X` and `Z` (there should be no `Y` there).

Comment: @masu: Then you should add `\unskip` to your macro (either at the start, or the end, or both). It wasn't clear from your original question.

Comment: My code had clearly different output. :) Doesn't matter... I'll try `\unskip`.

Comment: @masu: I've updated my answer. If you're not after any spaces when using `\nobf`, then `\mycommand` should probably be `\unskip\ignorespaces` (or perhaps one or the other). Let me know.

Comment: Thanks, `\unskip` is good for this question. `\ignorespaces` is good for my other use-case. Thank you.

Comment: you should probably have `\leavevmode` before the `\unskip` or the effect will be rather strange at the start of a paragraph (`\unskip` removes _vertical_ parskip in that position.)

Answer (score 6):

In latex internal code, any command that can be used in a paragraph, but provides no visible text, uses two internal commands: `\@bsphack` and `@esphack`. The first one tries to detect if a space preceded it and passes that information to the second. If the space was there `\@esphack` issues `\ignorespaces`. Thus:

```
\documentclass{article}
\DeclareRobustCommand\mycommand[1]{%
   \textbf{#1}}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\nobf[1]{% Use the "space hack"
    {\def\mycommand##1{\@bsphack\@esphack}#1}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\def\abc{X \mycommand{Y} Z}
\abc

\nobf{\abc}

\def\abc{X\mycommand{Y} Z}
\abc

\nobf{\abc}

\def\abc{X \mycommand{Y}Z}
\abc

\nobf{\abc}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Actually, in this resricted application, no internal commands are needed. In place of  `\def\mycommand##1{\@bsphack\@esphack}`
one can use
`\def\mycommand##1{\ifdim\lastskip>0pt \ignorespaces\fi}`